# Acer C720P Touch Screen

Tags: 13.10

I was wondering if anyone has gotten the Touch Screen working on the Acer C720P Chromebook yet? I have looked online and have not been able to find any information on it yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Update: for native touchscreen support (non chroot), I have posted on my google+ page on how I enabled the touchscreen

### https://plus.google.com/114358706658341629084/posts/Q9B4DiqWZ5E

If you use crouton to install/run Ubuntu 13.10, the touchscreen will work fine on the c720p. This is because it uses chroot and thus executes under the same kernel provided by ChromeOS.

I am running the Cinnamon desktop and have about 1.2 GB of RAM free after I start Ubuntu cinnamon and cairo-dock. You can easily toggle back and forth from ChromeOS at any time. Swap is on by default, so you get an extra 2GB of slow RAM there if you need it.

1) download and reference crouton to get it installed. It is just a binary, but it is best to read the readme here before you get started.

https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton

2) I used the following crouton command to install saucy with Cinnamon, Chrome and some other packages.

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -r saucy -t gtk-extra,cinnamon,audio,core,chrome,cli-extra,keyboard
```

3) To start the Ubuntu desktop crouton has installed:

```
sudo startcinnamon
```

4) Managing packages will need to be done with the command line apt or you can install synaptic like I did.

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

To run use:

```
sudo synaptic
```

(Not sure why apps don't request sudo properly when launched from the cinnamon GUI menu. I just installed this last night and don't have it all figured out yet!)

Comment: Unfortunately that option doesn't work for me, there's a few security issued with their install and I had some problems before with adding new users. But I was looking through their install scripts and if I can find the section that fixes the touch screen I will post that solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Agreed Z3R0, I understand what you mean without any elaboration. I want to run Linux native as well. I have booted Ubuntu off the USB, but found the touchscreen didn't work and wasn't quite ready to wipe ChromeOS and do a native install an hour after opening the box! I also wanted to give crouton a try to see how well things behaved using the base kernel. As far as the touchscreen, we likely need a kernel module. I don't think crouton is doing anything special there for us. I am going to research more and see what I can find.

Comment: P.S. I can see from the kernel log that the touch device is the Atmel maXTouch Touchsreen...I will see if I can compile a module for use with the mainline Ubuntu kernel. I believe this driver is open source since I have seen it before on other devices and kernels. It looks like many ChromeOS devices share the same kernel source tree...I am very familiar and used to fragmented Android kernels, so this would be a breath of fresh air. This is my first official ChromeOS device...having some fun learning.

Comment: Motley, Let me know if you get that working. I would love to see that running on the C720P. Currently I did the wipe and install on it and then I rand the kz917j script from http://goo.gl/kz917j - and that got the mouse and other things working. One of the few things I dont have working is the brightness from the keyboard shortcuts, even with custom shortcuts.. Im going to try to work on taking that from crouton source as well. It looked like the touch.sh script had the install for tocuhegg and they keyboard shortcuts for it as well.

Comment: Will do. I am running Mint native now. Installed directly from the Mint 16 media. I also used parts of the kz917j to get the touchpad working. Last night I made some modules built with the latest chromeos source and the atmel touchscreen driver is now detected and loaded on boot. It is somewhat operational and the device is present in sysfs, but something isn't right with the touch area and input. Not sure if Mint is the best OS to test a touchscreen with, so I will likely backup all my crap and move to Ubuntu again to do some testing with Unity.

Comment: Update: I am back on Ubuntu now using Unity. I have rebuilt the modules and the touchscreen is working great now in Unity! I also copied two firmware files over from chromeos (fw and config), but I am not sure they are needed. If the firmware is already flashed to the ts controller, it should just use what is resident...unless it has to be reloaded every time.  I may have to check for debug mode or place some of my own printk statements into the atmel source to better see what is going on with the firmware load.  I will try to provide a script for what I have done.

Answer (score 0):

Support for touchscreen is improved since 10.10. I know it works on various dells, I'm also using X220 tablet and it works well.

You may need some on screen keyboards for login and typing, try :

- Florence virtual keyboard
- GnomeOnscreenKeyboard : https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gok/
- Onboard : `sudo apt-get install onboard`

On KDE you can also use Wacom Tablet Settings to set it on/off

Comment: Thanks!But for me it doesn't even seem to detect the touch screen. No mouse control and no tablet detected in the tablet settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fully functional guide for getting ubuntu running on c720p. Check out the github page: https://github.com/visionect/c720p

Answer (score 0):

I use this computer too and I juste updated my Kernel to the version 3.17 (following [this tutorial](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/install-upgrade-kernel-3-17-ubuntu/)) and it works fine. The touchpad and touchscreen is implemented in this version.